# Creating USERs table in Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm pretty new to Express and NodeJS (less than a week) and I have a noobish question.

**Background**

I have made a REST API from a tutorial using Express and Passport for Authentication (which is just a basic auth with username and password and I get a token back in my requests).

I want to have something like Instagram or Facebook in which users have some information (name, birthdate etc.) and they can post texts.

> Model/Account.js

```
 import mongoose from 'mongoose';
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 import passportLocalMongoose from 'passport-local-mongoose';

 let Account = new Schema({
   email: String,
   password: String
 });

 Account.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
 module.exports = mongoose.model('Account', Account);
```

**Problem**

I don't know if I should add fields to the Model that I created for Authentication (which only has email and password) or I should create a separate Table, like USERS in my Database (I know it's a JSON file and not a database but don't know the technical name).

Please if any, give some hints here or keywords so that I can google myself.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you should add the field is existing model that you create for Authentication because if you made another model you have to repeat the data in your case it is email and password which does not make any sense and it also cause problems and confusion to fetch or manage data in both tables so i prefer you to insert the field in same model that you create for Authentication

Comment: And later if I add Facebook Auth it wouldn't affect anything? I mean if I add fields to this now, and in future decide to include FB auth, is it still ok?

Comment: yes it is ok you only nead to insert one more colum of fb token in model

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to reuse your accounts mongoose model for your user model.

Reason being is that you already have captured `email` and `password` which is what you would usually store in a `user` model.

You can add your additional fields to what you already have.

Comment: And later if I add Facebook Auth it wouldn't affect anything? I mean if I add fields to this now, and in future decide to include FB auth, is it still ok?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider a general schema for `account` authentication model and use the schema in all authentication cases. I prefer add other fields to exist model.

Comment: And later if I add Facebook Auth it wouldn't affect anything? I mean if I add fields to this now, and in future decide to include FB auth, is it still ok?

Comment: @AbedNaseri This's important to know that consider a base schema with a future mindset and I think you may not face the particular problem.